# Can't switch to the text mode

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, tty, text-mode

I was trying to stop xserver and install accelerated nvidia driver for cuda programming but for some reason when I type ctrl+alt+F1 (or F2-F6) I get "no signal" on my screen and no prompt after that. Did anyone face such problem? Any suggestions or presumptions? I have ubuntu 14.04 and graphical card NVidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti (in case it matters).
Moreover, I found out that after installing drivers for the graphical card, I can't see bios when rebooting.

Comment: Is it still an actual problem? Disrupting video signal (including text consoles) due to glitches of video driver isn’t unusual.

Comment: You using HDMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem today. In the end, the solution for me was to use:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And then edit this line to add nomodeset:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```